# How to deal with duplicate values in this query that uses one-to-many joins, and why do they appear even when using group_concat?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand why duplicate values appear in this case, if one of the tables is removed (hobbies, or interests) the query works as I expected (without duplicates).

My guess is that this happends because the `interests` and `hobbies` tables return a different number of rows for a student, I don't know if that is right.

What causes this behavior, and how should I pull the data without causing duplicates ?

In my head the query makes sense, give me all the students, and group their hobbies and interests on their unique id. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something.

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84d4a8/3)

```
CREATE TABLE students(
  student_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE interests (
  interest_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  interest_name varchar(255),
  student_id int
);

CREATE TABLE hobbies (
  hobby_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  hobby_name varchar(255),
  student_id int
);

INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES ('Jake'),('Mark'),('Ben');
INSERT INTO interests (interest_name, student_id) VALUES ('Math', '1'), ('Physics', '1'), ('Spanish', '2'), ('Nothing', '2');
INSERT INTO hobbies (hobby_name, student_id) VALUES ('Hiking', '1'), ('Sleeping', '1'), ('Running', '2');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  name, GROUP_CONCAT(interest_name) AS interests, GROUP_CONCAT(hobby_name) as hibbies
FROM 
  students
LEFT JOIN interests ON students.student_id = interests.student_id
LEFT JOIN hobbies ON students.student_id = hobbies.student_id
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| name |                 interests |                         hibbies |
|------|---------------------------|---------------------------------|
| Jake | Math,Physics,Math,Physics | Hiking,Hiking,Sleeping,Sleeping |
| Mark |           Spanish,Nothing |                 Running,Running |
|  Ben |                    (null) |                          (null) |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `GROUP_CONCAT`in a subquery, so you will not have doubles in it, through the crossjoin

```
SELECT 
  name, interests
  , hibbies
FROM 
  students
LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id,GROUP_CONCAT(interest_name) AS interests FROM interests GROUP BY  student_id) interests ON students.student_id = interests.student_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT student_id,GROUP_CONCAT(hobby_name) as hibbies FROM hobbies GROUP BY  student_id) hobbies  ON students.student_id = hobbies.student_id
GROUP BY students.student_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to aggregate along the separate dimensions separately -- using separate aggregation queries or a correlated subquery.

A quick-and-dirty solution is simply to use `group_concat(distinct)`:

```
SELECT s.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.interest_name) AS interests, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.hobby_name) as hobbies
FROM students s LEFT JOIN
     interests i
     ON s.student_id = i.student_id LEFT JOIN
     hobbies h
     ON s.student_id = h.student_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column names in a query that has more than one table reference.
- It is a good practice for the `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` columns to be consistent (although aggregating by a primary key is okay).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sql server is integrated properly into your visual studio

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?